# sas aggregate weekly, monthly

Tags: sas, aggregate

For the data set below(actual one is several thousand row long) I would like SAS to aggregate the income daily (many income lines everyday per machine), weekly, monthly (start of week is Monday, Start of month is 01 in any given year) by the machine. Is there a straight forward code for this? Any help is appreciated.

```
MachineNo  Date      income
1         01Jan2012  1500 
1         02Jan2012  2000
1         27Aug2012  300 
2         02Jan2012  1200
2         15Jun2012  50
3         03Mar2012  1000
4         08Apr2012  500
```

Answer (score 1):

`proc expand` and `proc timeseries` are excellent tools for accumulation and aggregation to different frequencies of series. You can combine both with by-group processing to convert to any time period that you need.

**Step 1: Sort by MachineNo and Date**

```
proc sort data=want;
    by MachineNo Date;
run;
```

**Step 2: Find the min/max end dates of your series for date alignment**

The `format=date9.` statement is important. For whatever reason, some SAS/ETS and HPF procedures require date literals for certain arguments.

```
proc sql noprint;
     select min(date) format=date9.,
            max(date) format=date9.
     into :min_date,
          :max_date
     from have;
quit;
```

**Step 3: Align each MachineNo by start/end date, and accumulate days per MachineNo**

The below code will get you aligned daily accumulation, remove duplicate days per machine, and set `Income` on any missing days to 0. This step will also guarantee that your series has equal time intervals per by-group, allowing you to run hierarchical time-series analyses without violating the equal-spaced interval assumption.

```
proc timeseries data=have
                out=want_day;
    by MachineNo;

    id date interval=day
            align=both
            start="&min_date"d
            end="&max_date"d;

    var income / accumulate=total setmiss=0;
run;
```

**Step 4: Aggregate aligned Daily to Weekly shifted by 1 day, Monthly**

SAS time intervals are able to be both multiplied and shifted. Since the standard weekday starts on a Sunday, we want to shift by 1 day to have it start on a Monday.

```
            Standard Week
2     3     4     5     6     7     1 
Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat   Sun

               Shifted
1     2     3     4     5     6     7
Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat   Sun
```

Intervals follow the format:

```
TimeInterval<Multiplier>.<Shift>
```

The standard shift interval is 1. For all intents and purposes, consider 1 as 0: 1 means it's unshifted. 2 means it's shifted by 1 period. Thus, for a week to start on a Monday, we want to use the interval `Week.2`.

```
proc expand data=want_day
            out=want_week
            from=day
            to=week.2;
    id date;
    convert income / method=aggregate observed=total;
run;
```

**Step 5: Convert Week to Month**

```
proc expand data=want_week
            out=want_month
            from=week.2
            to=month;
    id date;
    convert income / method=aggregate observed=total;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't have a license for SAS/ETS here's another way.

For the monthly data you can format the date in a proc means output.
I think WeekW. starts on Monday but it may not be in a format you want, so you'll need to create a new variable for week first if you wanted to use this method.

```
proc means data=have nway noprint;
class machineno date;
format date monyy7.;
var income;
output out=want sum(income)=income;
run;
```